# Swift 3; photo is not saving to photo gallery

Tags: swift, camera, save, swift3, photo-gallery

This code features a special camera that features a camera with a title nested in it. So when the photo is saved to the photo gallery the title is on the photo. The camera works great but the photo is not being saved. I just need to figure out how to save the photos to the photo gallery. I did change the plist to allow access to photo gallery and camera.

```
import Foundation
  import UIKit



class ViewController: UIViewController, OverlayViewControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var picker = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func letsDoThis(_ sender: AnyObject) {
             if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .rear) != nil {
        picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.showsCameraControls = false
        let overlayViewController = OverlayViewController(nibName:"OverlayView", bundle: nil)
        let overlayView: OverlayView = overlayViewController.view as! OverlayView
        overlayView.frame = self.picker.view.frame

        overlayView.delegate = self

        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: {


            self.picker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView
        })
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Camera", message: "That's weird. No camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "Alright Then.", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okay)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
           picker.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: Image Picker Controller Delegates

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(chosenImage, self,nil, nil)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("Canceled!!")
}

func didCancel(overlayView: OverlayView) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("dismissed!!")
}
func didShoot(overlayView: OverlayView) {
    picker.takePicture()
    overlayView.cameraLabel.text = "Shot Photo"
    print("Shot Photo")
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are saying that the call to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` isn't actually saving the image to the photo album, correct? Read the docs for `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` and make use of the extra parameters you are passing `nil` to so you can find out what is happening.

Comment: Yes that is correct. What do you mean by extra perimeters?

Comment: He means the two last parameters of `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`, which you set to `nil`. You can have a look here in the docs https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum . The last three parameters are optional. But this should not be the cause of your problem I think

Comment: @ronatory The point is that the cause of the issue can be determined by using the callback and its error.

Comment: there is no error it just does not save

Comment: @rmaddy thats true, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not the solution, but maybe it will take you further why the image is not saved (Hint from rmaddy in the comments of question). To see if there is an error while saving, use the `completionTarget` and `completionSelector` parameters like that (See also the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum)):

Add the `completionSelector` method:

```
func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
  guard error == nil else {
    print("Error saving image: \(error)")
    return
  }    
  print("Image saved successfully")
}
```

Change `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` to this

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(chosenImage, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

Comment: This does not work with me but the saved photo prints successfully where the problem is